# Comparing many const char* with one const char*

Tags: c

Might be basic one today.

I have an input as a const char* and I want to compare it with the many options of const char*. Something like I have written below.

str_equal - Think of it as a compare function for const char*. 'str' is the input const char*.

So, written like this:

```
bool function1(const char* str) {
  if (str_equal(str, "abc")) {
    // Do for abc
  } else if (str_equal(str, "def")) {
    // Do for def
  } else if (str_equal(str, "ghi")) {
    // Do for ghi
  } ...
  ...
}
```

Wondering what are the other possible ways to achieve this. As you can see, it looks very ugly.

Comment: Can you not maintain an array of the `char[]` literals you're comparing against. Then it's a case of iterating through that array. But if what you do differs according to the match, then you could use a table of function pointers, assuming the arity of each function is the same.  Else what you have is probably best.

Comment: @Bathsheba, Then how will do different "Do for ...". Same thing. Is'nt it?

Comment: If you want to handle two cases with the same code, just or the conditions together, or, with the table approach, set the same function pointer for several entries.

Comment: @Hemant It will be a bit more compact code wise. Of course, in the end you need to list all strings unless there is some law to the strings you can generate from.

Comment: I think it would be best if you give pseudo-code of what you're aiming at (ball park).

Comment: @cmaster, No. I need to do different things for different cases.

Comment: As long as performance is not a problem, @Bathsheba 's advise is sound. Only when you need to worry about performance should you start thinking about implementing a hash table: It's the only data structure that allows you to lookup a string key in `O(1)`.

Comment: No need for a `str_equal()` function.   The standard library provides `strcmp()`.   Beyond that, assuming the strings being compared against are known at compile time, one option is an array of strings to be compared with (in a loop) to obtain the index of the matching string.   An associated array of function pointers can then map the obtained index to any function desired.   There are plenty of alternatives that don't require maintaining a long series of `if`/`else if` statements.

Comment: @Peter: You have assumed `str_equal` returns true iff two strings are the same length with the same characters. But it could be any [*equivalence relation*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), such as returning true iff two strings are isentical except for case.

Comment: Note that Eric is using iff to mean "if, and only if": isentical is a typo.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -  I assumed nothing.  The question was about alternatives to having a long set of `if`/`else`.  My point was that introducing a more "general" string comparison gave no useful information pertinent to the question.   Simply using `strcmp()` - a function C developers with even moderate experience will recognise - is sufficient for purposes of the question.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Thanks for the clarification, but I am familiar with math shorthand/notation and (on this and many other sites :-) ) am used to typos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an array of structures:

```
static bool do_abc(void)
{
  // ...
}

bool dispatch(const char *str)
{
  static const struct {
    const char *key;
    bool (*func)(void);
  } funcs[] = {
    { "abc", do_abc },
    { "def", do_def },
    { "ghi", do_ghi },
  };
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof funcs / sizeof *funcs; ++i)
  {
    if(strcmp(funcs[i].text, str) == 0)
      return funcs[i].func();
  }
  return false;
}
```

This assumes that all the functions have the same signature, otherwise it's hard to generalize.

By the way, this can be called an example of "data-driven code", which is often nice.

Comment: Note that for larger tables, you would rather use binary search, and for even larger tables a hash table. So how to implement this in the best way depends on the nature of the data.

Answer (score 1):

depends on your needs there are several other way you can use.

For example, you an initially create a sorted array of strings which you compare against and use binary search: https://linux.die.net/man/3/bsearch.

You can use hash tables or trees as well, just a bit more complicated.

In some cases you might even create a combined string of all your strings like "abcdefdhi" and use `strstr` to find the string in a singe operation.